# Требуется реализовать поиск в двух моделях ASP.NET MVC Core одновременно с выводом результата в представление

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Требуется реализовать поиск в нескольких моделях/сущностях.

Итак, есть такие модели (таблицы в БД - использую EF), очень похожие по своим полям, но содержат разные данные конечно:

```
 public class VerseModel
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string MainVerse { get; set; }
    public string VersePath { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string DateVerse { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}



 public class Verse2Model
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Main2Verse { get; set; }
    public string Verse2Path { get; set; }
    public string Author2 { get; set; }
    public string Date2Verse { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created2On { get; set; }
}
```

И так же есть контроллер, которые собственно и принимает значение, по которому надо искать. Тип данных - string.

```
 private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;


    public SearchController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _db = context;
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SearchView(string item)
    {

     return View(_db.Verse.Where(x => x.VersePath.Contains(item)).ToList());
    }
```

И конечно представление,куда выводится результат поиска.

@using VerseWebSite.Models;

```
<h2 class="h2addverse">Результаты поиска</h2>


@foreach (var search in Model)
{
    <h3 class="nametextverse">@search.VersePath</h3>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-7 col-xs-10 col-sm-9 col-lg-offset-4 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-offset-1">
                @Html.Raw(search.MainVerse)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

Вопрос: как сделать поиск в двух моделях? Что бы слово, которое ввел пользователь в text-box было одновременно найдено в двух моделях и результат выведен во вьюху? 
Пользователь осуществляет поиск по названию, а конкретно по по полю  VersePath. Т.е. ввел название произведения, нажал "бутон" :) и получил результат, есть ли произведение с таким названием на сайте. 
На данный момент как видно из контроллера поиск происходит только в 1 модели и отлично работает. 
НО! Как сделать поиск и в первой модели и во второй одновременно и вывести это все по вьюху? Буду рад любому совету, а то я уже голову сломал воюя с рэзором и его бандлами. Пытался сделать через if как-то слишком криво получается...

ПС. Позже я это все сделаю через паттерн Репозиторий, дабы напрямую не обращаться к БД из контроллера. Это  так сказать "черновой" код для проверки функционала.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SearchView(string item)
{
  List<VerseModel> model = _db.Verse.Where(x => x.VersePath.Contains(item)).ToList();
  var m2 = _db.Verse2.Where(x => x.Verse2Path.Contains(item));
  foreach(var i2 in m2)
    model.Add(new VerseModel() {
      Id = i2.Id,
      MainVerse = i2.Main2Verse,
      ...
    });
  return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Интересно.. Спасибо огромное, я попробую. А как это все корректно отобразить во вьюхе? На моем примере выше.

Comment: @AndriiTkachenko Не понял вопроса.

Comment: С двумя моделями работает отлично! Огромное вам спасибо. Теперь ломаю голову на 5 моделей. Они точно такие же, только там цыфра меняется: Verse3Path,Verse4Path и так далее. Данная логика подойдет?

Comment: @AndriiTkachenko Можно решить это на уровне базы, создав в ней `VIEW` с `UNION [ALL]`, который соберет данные из всех таких таблиц.

Comment: В том то и проблема, что БД трогать нельзя. :( Только кодом :(